# Problema de visualización cardview

Tags: android, android-studio, cardview

He estado tratando de implementar el cardview para mi aplicación pero siempre me aparece en color gris como en la imagen. He intentado cambiar el SDK porque instala la nueva versión de android studio que trae el 29,ni así he podido resolverlo.

[image: Layout]

Este es el codigo de mi xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




</LinearLayout>
```

y este el build.gradle que modique a 28, viene con 29

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

}
```

no se si tengo algo que ver que el cardview no este en version 29, espeor su ayuda.

Comment: No depende de la versión del SDK usado, actualiza Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas utlizando androidX, por lo que deberias usar

```
 implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

y tu xml deberia quedar de la sig forma

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

Answer (score 2):

Debe cambiar la implementacion de Cardview usted actualmente usa

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

y debe sustituirla por

```
  implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

adicional en el xml deberia cambiar la declaracion de su CardView

a algo como esto:

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
```

> Para más información consulte  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para que pueda renderizar en la vista de diseño tu `CardView`, depende principalmente de la versión Android Studio, te sugiero actualizar a Android Studio 3.5 o 3.5.1 como mínimo.

---

información extra:

Si estas haciendo uso de las library `AndroidX`, debes cambiar la referencia del `CardView`, usando en tu `build.gradle` la referencia:

```
 implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

y cambiar la clase de tu CardView a:

```
   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
```